# Display dynamic values based on slicer option

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a client that asks for a slicer with 3 options:

1. All employees
2. By employee (if this is selected, then a they need to select from another slicer the employee's name)
3. By project

Data source is Azure SQL Server. He wants to display the total values of the columns based on the selected slicer option.

Has anyone done that before? How can I create these values and put them in a slicer as the client wants?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?